# Wordpress Check-Boxes Filter Custom Category PHP

Tags: forms, wordpress, checkbox, filter

I am currently working on a website..

I need the following functionality:

I have several categories for colors and photos that relate to these categories

category examples:

red
green
blue
orange
purple
yellow

I am trying to make a form on my wordpress HOME page that will allow me to check a category and then filter my current displayed posts by that category.
I would like to remain on the home page during this process

I would also like to figure out how to eliminate the "submit" button and have the form submit every time a box is checked or un-checked.

I am using the latest version of wordpress and the twentytwelve theme

So far this function will filter post by category:

```
function filter_color( $query ) {
$query->set( 'cat', '2' ); 
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'filter_color' );
```

I am just not sure how to create the checkboxes that will trigger the filter. I do not know where my form should "submit" to (index.php?) and I'm not sure how to get the submitted data to show up. Also, I would like ALL boxes checked by default and the form to save the data as color options are un-checked or re-checked.

Please, any links to good reference materials and any help with this would be greatly appreciated as I have been stumped currently.

Thanks in advance!